# CGAL 4.4/4.3 cygCGAL_Core-10.dll does not work

Tags: cygwin, cgal

I am a fresh. I try to use CGAL under Cygwin. 
CGAL seems to be installed successfully, but cannot compile any example,
when i try to 'cmake .' (succeeded) ->  'make' (failed)
they throw me following bomb,

```
 make
Scanning dependencies of target delaunay
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/delaunay.dir/delaunay.cpp.o
In file included from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/CoreDefs.h:41:0,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/CORE.h:39,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE_coercion_traits.h:33,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE_Expr.h:29,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/delaunay.cpp:2:
/home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/extLong.h:171:8: warning: ‘CORE::extLong::extLong(int)’ redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage [enabled by default]
 inline extLong::extLong(int i) : val(i), flag(0) {
        ^
/home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/extLong.h:292:13: warning: ‘bool CORE::extLong::isNaN() const’ redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage [enabled by default]
 inline bool extLong::isNaN() const {
             ^
In file included from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloat.h:38:0,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/RealRep.h:38,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/Real.h:40,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/ExprRep.h:42,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/Expr.h:42,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/CORE.h:68,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE_coercion_traits.h:33,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE_Expr.h:29,
                 from /home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/delaunay.cpp:2:
/home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloatRep.h:266:8: warning: ‘CORE::BigFloatRep::BigFloatRep(const CORE::BigInt&, long unsigned int, long int)’ redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage [enabled by default]
 inline BigFloatRep::BigFloatRep(const BigInt& I, unsigned long er, long ex)
        ^
/home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/../../include/CGAL/CORE/BigFloatRep.h:362:13: warning: ‘bool CORE::BigFloatRep::isZeroIn() const’ redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage [enabled by default]
 inline bool BigFloatRep::isZeroIn() const {
             ^
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/lib/cygCGAL_Core-10.dll', needed by 'delaunay.exe'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:63: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/delaunay.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/delaunay.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i have no idea at all.
please help me. thank you very much!!!!

Comment: What was your build directory while building the CGAL libraries?

Comment: it was "/home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/",   and one more question for the latest XCode 5.1, CGAL does not work, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure of my answer, but it seems that, when you have configured the example inside `/home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/examples/Core/`, using CMake, you have specified `/home/JIN/CGAL-4.4/config` as the value of the `CGAL_DIR` variable. That directory contains the file `CGALConfig.cmake` that is intended to be used once CGAL is installed. Instead, you should use `/home/JIN/CGAL-4.4` as value of `CGAL_DIR`. That directory contains the `CGALConfig.cmake` file that must be used to use the in-place build tree of CGAL, without installation.

Comment: Thank you Irineau, but problem still there, I have seen a lot of problems solution given by you, thanks .... A question more, how can I use CGAL on MAC with the XCode 5.1,   since I update my mac, I cannot use CGAL anymore....

Comment: @ShengyeJin Why have you accept my answer if that does not solve your problem? Thanks, anyway. The clang compiler of XCode 5.1 is support since CGAL-4.4. If you have an issue with that version of XCode, please fill another question on Stackoverflow, or post to the CGAL-discuss mailing-list.

Comment: Thank you Irineau, actually I did ask on CGAL-discuss, but it seems nobody interested on my question. I will try CGAL 4.4 .